# Load AJAX Response into Browser (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following JS code to load a remote page:

```
function SendCustomRequest() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("GET", "/test.html", false);
    request.send(null);
    alert(request.responseText);
}
```

This works fine, the HTML content of `test.html` is shown in the alert message box.

Now I need to show this whole `test.html` page in the browser window, but without jQuery. Not a `div` or so in the original page (where the AJAX call happens), but that page has to be completely replaced by the content of `test.html`. And it has to work in IE8.

Any ideas?

PS: The AJAX call may be async as well, if needed.

Comment: Does the `<head>` need to be replaced?

Comment: You will NOT be able to change the whole document. You could append to the existing page document, but a full document replacement will need to use a `window.location` outside of AJAX to fetch the page.

Comment: Why has my question been down-voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that page has to be completely replaced by the content of test.html

I don't think that is a good idea (as I know that is impossible in some browsers).

You can open new window and then put content of `test.html` there.

```
function SendCustomRequest() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("GET", "/test.html", false);
    request.send(null);

    var newWindow = window.open("");
    newWindow.document.write(request.responseText);
}
```

check out [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) to know how to set options to window.

Also check [MSDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Ohh I think that is a nice solution as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> that page has to be completely replaced by the content of `test.html`

Set `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to `request.responseText`

```
request.onload = request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  document.documentElement.outerHTML = request.responseText
}
```

Comment: He marked the request as synchronous, so `onload` may not work here,

Comment: @TbWill4321: An async AJAX call is ok as well, if necessary. I have updated my original posting accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You say "***...but that page has to be completely replaced by the content of test.html***"
If I take your statement exactly it says that **everything** of the page has to be replaced.

AJAX makes sense when **parts of a page** should be updated.

Directly issueing GET requests are appropriate if the **whole page** should be replaced.

So I would suggest not to use AJAX in this case.
The URL (plus parameters) you are providing to the AJAX call could be assinged to **window.location.href** in your script. The browsers would then directly issue the corresponding GET request and update the entire page automatically.

See the example below:

```js
function getNewPage(url,parameters) {
   alert("Issueing the GET request: "+url+"?"+parameters);
   window.location.href = url + "?" + parameters;
}

function doOnload() {
   getNewPage("http://www.example.com/test.html","par1=val1&par2=val2");
}
```

```html
<body onload="doOnload(); return false;">
   <p>Some dummy text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. The reason why I wanted to use `XMLHttpRequest()` is because I need to add a custom header to the HTTP request. Is there any way to do so when using the approach you suggest?

Comment: I'm afraid: no! Assigning an URL to "window.location.href" has nearly the same effect as an <a href="...">...</a> link has. The user's browser sets up the connection and issues a GET request without the possibility to manipulate headers.

Comment: Just for completeness: do you control the URL that should be called here? I.e. can you perhaps modify the code (I think it must be a script or program) that is executed when this GET request is issued? If yes: you could accept the same data as is accepted via the header also as a GET parameter value, and add this data to the "parameters", e.g. "&XYZ_header_data=data".

Comment: Unfortunately we have to use HTTP headers to add some custom data, due to security reasons within the company.